# Build don't see it in the App Store Connect

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect

I generate binary with Xcode correctly, but I don't see it in the App Store Connect.
It does not end error
[image]

Comment: Did you submit the archive from Xcode? Did Apple send you an email that processing is complete?

Comment: Yes I submit the archive from Xcode